# Showing a set is equivalent to Z.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am attempting to show that the set {5n | n = 1,2,...} is equivalent to Z. I know that I am searching for a 1-1, onto function that maps the set to the set of all integers, but how do I go about this?

Listed below is my initial attempt:

Since I am trying to map {5, 10, 15, 20, ...} onto {...,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3} could I use the function f such that f(n) = n/5 when n is even and (-1)(n/5) when n is odd??

Comment: This doesn't work as is, since what would map to 1?

Comment: Is the given set not equivalent to the set of all integers? I'm not having any success constructing a function that maps the given set to {...,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,...}

Comment: FYI,  the word you should be looking for is "Has the same cardinality", not "equiivalent"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define $f:\{5n $|$ n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ by $f(m) = \begin{cases} 
      \frac{m}{10} & m\equiv 0 (\mod 2) \\
      \frac{-(m-5)}{10} & m \not\equiv 0 (\mod 2)
   \end{cases}
$

So here $5\mapsto 0$, $10\mapsto 1$, $15\mapsto -1$, $20\mapsto 2$, ...

This problem is essentially the same as constructing a bijection from $\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$, only here you are working with multiples of $5$.

Comment: This may be a stupid question but what are the conditions given in the function f(m) listed to the far right? (i.e. what does the m = 0 ( mod 2) mean?

Comment: I used $\equiv 0 (\mod 2)$ to mean even, and $\not\equiv 0 (\mod 2)$ to mean odd. That notation is from modular arithmetic. For an integer $x$, $x \equiv 0 (\mod n)$ for some positive integer $n$ means $x$ is divisible by n.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for your help, I've been searching everywhere for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Consider any sequence A(1),A(2),A(3),... and any "double sequence"  ...,B(-2),B(-1),B(0),B(1),B(2),... Re-arrange the double sequence as B(0),B(1),B(-1),B(2),B(-2),B(3),B(-3),... and match them up with the first sequence.That is A(1) to B(0),A(1) to B(1),A(2) to B(-1),A(3) to B(2),A(4) to B(-2), A(5) to B(3),etc.